# Is there any way to get Google Auth Token, without taking user's permission android

Tags: android, google-authentication

I want to take out the GoogleAuthToken, of the user using following method:

private class RetrieveTokenTask extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String accountName = params[0];
        String scopes = "oauth2:openid";
        String token = null;
        try {
            token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), accountName, scopes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQ_SIGN_IN_REQUIRED);
        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return token;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        if (s != null) {
            Log.e("AccessToken", s);
            preferences.edit().putString(PreferencesConstants.GOOGLE_AUTH_TOKEN, s).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: This method successfully gives me the token, BUT THE PROBLEM IS: It asks for user's permission with Allow and Deny for the first time. (which I dont want). Is there any way I can take out the token, without user's permission. ?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to API access given to the application. For each developer machine SHA1 should be given to API and create separate Android API key for the each SHA1.

Go to console.developers.google.com -> select your project
API & AUTH -> credentials.
Create new client Key (though it has other client keys).
select installed app -> android.
Give your package name and SHA1 correctly select OK.